# Can I rename a file someone shared with me?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, google-drive-sharing

I have several clients who share docs with me. I can see these when I go to docs.google.com. Unfortunately, clients name their files things like "strategy" and I have many clients with different strategies.

Is there a way so that I could rename the files, or tag them visibly, or put them in my own folders/dirs, so that *to me* the file might appear as "Example Organization: strategy"? I don't want to rename the file as *they* see it.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that what you can do is "create a shortcut in Google Drive". I believe every google file (doc, sheet...) is already 'in' google Drive, *somewhere*, and that you can rationalise this by making a folder structure in your Google Drive space.

e.g. find the file in the list of "Shared with me" files, select it, click the drive + icon and then click the little right-arrow by the "My Drive" menu item, and from there you can select an existing folder or crete a new one.

It's awkward and doesn't seem to support mulitple selection/bulk operations, but at least it's one way to rationalise/find things.

Comment: Besides creating shortcuts you could use Google Drive workspaces, use Google Chat rooms, use your web browser bookmarking tool, among many other options.